# UIActionSheet will not act until buttons are tapped twice in iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiactionsheet

I have a `UIActionSheet` which I create with the following code.

```
 UIActionSheet *popupQuery2 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose" 
                                                          delegate:nil 
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                            destructiveButtonTitle:@"Accept Friendship" 
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Do not accept friendship",@"Check profile", nil];
popupQuery2.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[popupQuery2 setDelegate:self];
popupQuery2.tag=3;
[popupQuery2 showInView:self.view.superview];
[popupQuery2 release];
```

The code is working on iOS 5.0 fine. The issue is in 4.0. I have to tap twice on the buttons of the `UIActionSheet` to dismiss it! Anyone got this issue before?

Comment: Why are you doing `[popupQuery2 setDelegate:self]` instead of just setting the delegate when you create the sheet two lines earlier?

Comment: Same thing happens i have tried that...any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help but the problem was that the ibaction was called two times in ios4! So i searched in stackoverflow and i have found this

if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
        return;

I have putted the above code in my ibaction and it worked!!!

Thank you again i really appreciate your help! Hope this helps someone else because i have been looking into it for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem in iOS 8, using `UIAlertController` with style `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`. While the stefanosn's own answer solve for him, it is not the case for me.

My problem is that the first tap on the action sheet (on any button) is ignored.

Turned out it got to do with my text field's keyboard interfering with the touches.

The fix is to dismiss the keyboard first, then present the action sheet.

```
[textfield resignFirstResponder];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```